# about guest in the kvm to handle the external interrupt and external interrupt

Tags: linux-kernel, virtualization, kvm

I'm new to kvm, can someone explain it's process when guest handle a external interrupt or the emulated device interrupt?

Thanks
Amos

Comment: This seems more of an architecture/design question than programming per se. Perhaps you would have better luck asking it on either [unix.se] or [su]?

Answer (score 3):

In x86 architecture, Intel in this case, most interrupts will cause CPU VM exit, which means the control of CPU will return to host from guests.

So the processes are

1. CPU is used by guest OS in VMX non-root mode.
2. CPU is aware of an interrupt coming.
3. CPU's control returns to host running in VMX root mode. (VM exit)
4. The host (KVM) handles the interrupt.
5. Host executed VMLAUNCH instruction to let CPU transfer to VMX non-root mode again for running 
   guest code.
6. Repeat 1.

Comment: SHORT ,SWEET & PRECISE EXCELLENT

Answer (score 2):

If you are new to kvm, you should first read a few papers about how kvm module works (I assume you know basic idea of virtualization).How it uses qemu to do i/o emulation etc.
I recommend you read these papers:

kvm: the Linux Virtual Machine Monitor: https://www.kernel.org/doc/mirror/ols2007v1.pdf#page=225
Kernel-based Virtual Machine Technology : http://www.fujitsu.com/downloads/MAG/vol47-3/paper18.pdf KVM: Kernel-based Virtualization Driver: http://www.linuxinsight.com/files/kvm_whitepaper.pdf

These are papers written by guys who started kvm.(  they are short and sweet :)  )
After this you should start looking at the documentation of the kvm in the source code especially the file api.txt its very good.

Then I think you can jump into the source code to understand how things actually work.

Cheers